# How to check the API for correctness in Python?

Tags: python, api

I have two functions, one makes a request to the API, the second checks this request. I can't figure out how to use the `check_response()` function to check that a valid request has arrived. The `check_response()` function checks the API response for correctness. As a parameter, the function receives an API response reduced to Python data types. If the API response meets expectations, then the function should return a list of homework (it may be empty), available in the API response by the 'homeworks' key.

```
def get_api_answer(current_timestamp):
    timestamp = current_timestamp or int(time.time())
    params = {'from_date': timestamp}
    response = requests.get(ENDPOINT, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return response.json()
```

```
def check_response(response):
    return response['homeworks'][0]
```

Request example:

```
{'current_date': 1660744525,
 'homeworks': [{'date_updated': '2022-08-09T08:02:19Z',
                'homework_name': 'Finegorko__hw43_final.zip',
                'id': 412659,
                'lesson_name': 'Project of sprint: follow to authors',
                'reviewer_comment': 'Good! Accepted.',
                'status': 'approved'}]}
```

Comment: Can you explain, in your own words, what the `[0]` in your code means and why it's there?

Comment: `[0]` allows me to select the most recent homework and manipulate it further. If you suggest a better idea, I will be grateful.

Comment: when I request an API, I get this [response](https://i.imgur.com/w2bPtlS.png)

Comment: Based on the question text, you said you want a list of homework, but the code returns only one homework. Which one do you want?

Comment: in the future, I carry out such manipulations with the response from the API [parse_status()](https://i.imgur.com/H5Msce3.png)

Comment: I suppose `[0]` is more correct to use elsewhere? the initial question is to check the API for correctness, I don't understand how to make an `expected_response` with how to compare it with a actual request.